# Pynput doesn’t recognize letter key and number key

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, error-handling, pynput

When I used the pynput module, it only recognize keys like cmd, shift, option, control and don’t recognize letter key(asdf..) and number key(12345…) pls help.

Comment: I need your code to adequately answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.